# My R function returns <dbl [1]> in a calculated column instead of the number. How do I fix this?

Tags: r

I wrote a function that would calculate percentage change for a specific column. The values are iterated in the column based on a for loop. The parameters of the function are the table name and the column name based on which the calculations will be performed.
However, instead of getting a number in the newly calculated column, I keep getting  against each row.

```
func_per_change <- function(table,column_name){

    for (i in 1:4) {
        ifelse(i==1, table$new_col[i] <- 0,(table$new_col[i] <- 
        (table[i,column_name]/table[(i-1),column_name]) - 1))
    }

    return (table)
}
```

Actual

```
month sales new_col  
  <chr> <dbl> <list>   
1   jan       100      "dbl [1]"
```

Expected

```
month sales new_col  
  <chr> <dbl> <list>   
1 jan     100        0
```

Comment: I guess using `if (i==1) {table$new_col[i] <- 0} else {table$new_col[i] <- 
        (table[i,column_name]/table[(i-1),column_name]) - 1}` instead of `ifelse` should solve this problem. In general, I'd advise against using `table` as a name as it is already a build in function. A small example with data would help.

Comment: @kath, Sure. Thanks for the suggestion. Actually, I just changed the code a bit and it worked. It required using [[i,column_name]] instead of [i,column_name].


    perc_change <- function(table,column_name){
  
      for (i in 1:4) {
      ifelse(i==1, table$perc_change[i] <- 0,(table$perc_change[i] <- 
    ((table[[i,column_name]]/table[[(i-1),column_name]]) - 1)))
        }
      return (table)}

Comment: `ifelse` is the vectorized version of if...else and the way you are using it, it should be replace by if...else... IMHO. Also you might want to have a look at the `lag`-function from dplyr.

Comment: `if` on scalars, `ifelse` on vectors.

Comment: perc_change2 <- function(d_set,column_name){
  
  for (i in 1:4) {
    if (i==1) {d_set$perc_change[i] <- 0}
    else {d_set$perc_change[i] <- ((d_set[i,column_name]/d_set[(i-1),column_name]) - 1)}
  }
  return (d_set)}

This also gives the same output as complained.